# How to read .txt files from github into Google colab

Tags: python-3.x, github, google-colaboratory

I have folder in github which contains text files and when I tried to read  below code in Google colab I'm getting error

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   'https://github.com/Jainu-s/urldata/tree/master/al?raw=true'

```
loc = 'https://github.com/Jainu-s/urldata/tree/master/al?raw=true'
#uploaded = files.upload()
os.chdir(loc)
filelist = os.listdir()
#print (len((pd.concat([pd.read_csv(item, names=[item[:-4]]) for item in filelist],axis=1))))

data = []
path = loc
files = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(f)]
for f in files:
    with open(f,'r') as myfile:
        data.append(myfile.read())


df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Data'])
print (df.shape)
```

Comment: Why do you want to read a text file from GitHub? Just simply download it locally?

Comment: Every file in github has a raw link, for example for your first text file : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Jainu-s/urldata/master/al/abescoldbeer.com.txt, you can modify the last part of the link and try to read the files.

Comment: I added to the raw link but still I cannot read as it throws an error

Comment: I have the same issue. Reading other files types such as CSV and EXCEL directly from Github works perfectly, but .txt is a problem. I need to read the .txt files from Github because members of my team update them regularly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download all files in that directory to Colab first with:

```
!npx degit Jainu-s/urldata/al -f
```

Then, you can loop it like local files.

Comment: That worked fine thank you and which programming language this code is belong to

Comment: degit is written in JavaScript.

Answer (score 7):

```py
import base64
import requests

master = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Jainu-s/urldata/master/al/abescoldbeer.com.txt"
req = requests.get(master)
req = req.text
print(req)
```

In this way you can read all the files using a for loop modifying the master string

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38497199/10077354 You can refer this link to know about reading github files.

Comment: For one file it was working fine but loop I cannot retrieve data from folder

Comment: Try referring here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36638584/github-get-a-list-of-all-files-in-a-repository-from-raw-githubusercontent for listing all the files.

Answer (score 1):

Even though @korakot's response is valid, as an alternative solution:

```
!git clone https://github.com/Jainu-s/urldata.git
path = '/content/urldata/al'

%cd urldata #go to the directory where git clone says *Cloning into*

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
  print(files)
```