# How does !npx degit work in Google Colab?

Tags: github, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to read files from my Github repository in Google Colab. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61723047/how-to-read-txt-files-from-github-into-google-colab) that instructed me to use:

```
!npx degit Jainu-s/urldata/al -f
```

Which copies the files from my repository as local Colab files. It works perfectly, but I have no ideia what this code does exactly and I could not find any Colab documentation on it.

Can anyone explain to me how it works? What is its syntax, what does it do? And what are the options I could use with it?

Comment: `npx` runs a binary from a npm package, which in this case is [degit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/degit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read its documentation.

```
https://github.com/Rich-Harris/degit
```

Basically,

- the program is degit
- npx is to execute without install it
- /al means you download that directory content
- f is force download, because the directory is not empty

To read more

```
!npx degit --help
```

Comment: Is it possible to use this approach with os.walk()? I used this and it says it cloned but when I try with os.walk it returns nothing.